# @extends and @yield in laravel not working for second blade file

Tags: php, css, vue.js, laravel-blade, laravel-9

@extends , @section and @yield work for the main welcome page, but I made a new product-gel.blade.php file in view and used the @extends and @section and @endsection on it but it doesnt seem to work.
Here is the yield place

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\resources\stylecss\style.css">
        @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
        <script></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <section id="header">    
                <div class="main-pages-box">
                    <div class="main-pages">
                        <a href="../resources/main_page/customer-care.php" class="customer-care">CUSTOMER CARE</a>
                        @if (Route::has('login'))
                                @auth
                                    
                                <a> {{Auth::user()->name}} </a>
            
                                <a href="{{ Auth::logout() }}">LOG OUT</a>
            
                                @else
                                    <a href="{{ route('login') }}">LOGIN</a>
            
                                    @if (Route::has('register'))
                                        <a href="{{ route('register') }}">REGISTER</a>
                                    @endif
                                @endauth
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="main-bar">
                    <div class="daraz-logo-container">
                        <a href="../public/index.php"><img src="../resources/images/daraz_logo.png" alt="daraz_logo" class="daraz-logo"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="search-box-container">
                        <form onSubmit="searching();">
                            <input type="text" placeholder=" Search on Daraz" name="search" class="search-bar" id="text-to-search">   
                            <a onclick="searching();" class="search-btn"></a>
                            <a href="../resources/main_page/cart.php" class="cart-btn"><img src="../resources/images/cart-icon.png" alt=""></a>
                            <a href="../resources/main_page/downloadnow.php" class="downloadnow-icon"><img src="../resources/images/downloadnow-icon.png" alt=""></a>
                        </form>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <script src="../resources/scriptfiles/searching.js"></script>
                



            @yield('content')


            
            
            <section id="footer">
                <div class="customer-care-end">
                    <h1>Customer Care</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Help Center</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">How to Buy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Corporate & Bulk Purchasing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Returns & Refunds</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Daraz Shop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Purchase Protection</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Daraz Pick up Points</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Fulfulled By Daraz (FBD)</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="codenthx">
                    <div class="QRcode"></div>
                    <div class="appdl">
                        <div class="QRthx"></div>
                        <p>Happy Shopping</p>
                    </div>
            
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the new file im trying to extend on (removed the html file and just put it a header testing file to see if it works)

```
@extends('layouts.frontend')
@section('content')

<div>
    <h1>testing</h1>
</div>

@endsection
```

This works on the welcome.blade.php file but not on the product-gel.blade.php file.

this is what the directory is looking like for the welcome page
view > welcome.blade.php

and for the product one
view > produ > product-gel.blade.php

I have also tried moving the gel.blade.php file outside of produ folder like this
view > product-gel.blade.php

But that also doesnt work, I am still new to laravel so dont know what I am doing wrong here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpGNI.jpg
This is what it looks like.

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: I dont get an error, it runs fine just doesnt work, it shows the @ stuff as plain text in the browser